# Change a date's timezone to UTC without changing the date itself

Tags: javascript

Say if the date is:

`var now = new Date(); // Tue Apr 19 2022 13:12:41 GMT+0530`

I need to change only the timezone to UTC. so `Tue Apr 19 2022 13:12:41 GMT+0000` in above case.
Things like `toISOString()` gives actual UTC i.e. modified date value after adjusting the offset.

Comment: Why? Your variable would represent a completely different moment in time!

Comment: `now` is a UTC date. It's only the string output that needs to change, not the date itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're basically asking for this:

```js
const now = new Date;
const utc = new Date(Date.UTC(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate(), now.getHours(), now.getMinutes(), now.getSeconds()));

console.log(now, utc);
```

This creates a date in your local timezone, and then another date with the same year, month, day, hour, minute and second *value*, but in the UTC timezone.

What sense that makes is another topic…

Comment: Misses the `getMilliseconds()` one.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add the timezone difference:

```
let x = new Date()
x.setMinutes(x.getMinutes() - x.getTimezoneOffset())
```